# Re-using a main menu item as popup menu

Tags: menu, c++builder, c++builder-2007

I have an application with a form that has a main menu. Now I would like to show a popup menu (MPopup) that contains an exact copy of the items in one of its sub-menus (MEdit):

```
class MyForm
{
__published:
TMainMenu *MainMenu1;
TMenuItem *MFile;
TMenuItem *MEdit;
// ...
TPopupMenu *MPopup;
// ...
```

How can I populate the popup menu without having to manage redundant items? All menus in question are static, no dynamic population.

System info: RAD Studio 2007 (C++ Builder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot share menu items between multiple menus.  You have to make a copy of the items in each menu.  In your Form's constructor, I would loop through the MainMenu items and create new PopupMenu sub-items that have the same property values, OnClick event handlers, etc as needed.

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, you can place a `TActionList` on your Form and fill it with `TAction` objects that define your desired menu item properties and event handlers, and then you can create menu items in both menus as needed that simply refer to the same `TAction`s via the `TMenuItem::Action` property.

Comment: And using for loop...?

Comment: @kokbira not sure I understand what you are asking for